# Replacing part of a string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

In my game I have figure codes for the clothes players wear, so like...

```
hd-185-1.ch-235-1408.lg-3116-85-1408.ha-1002-1408.sh-3115-1408-1408.ca-1805-64.
hd-185-12.ch-235-1408.lg-3116-85-1408.ha-1002-1408.sh-3115-1408-1408.ca-1805-64.
hr-165-52.hd-205-30.ca-1802-63.wa-2012-1408.lg-270-63.ha-3655-0.ch-806-1412.sh-305-110.he-1601-0
```

hd is for head, ha is for hair, sh is for shoes, lg is for legs and so on.. I am trying to replace the skin color of a players appearence by replacing part of the string...

Here is what I've tried...

```
public string GetHead()
{
    return FigureCode.Split('.').FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("hd"));
}

public void UpdateSkin(string skinCode)
{
    var headPart = GetHead();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headPart))
    {
        return;
    }

    var skin = headPart.Split('-')[2];

    FigureCode = FigureCode.Replace(headPart, headPart.Replace(skin, skinCode));
}
```

This works with the first figure code example in this question (IE `hd-185-1.ch-235-1408.lg-3116-85-1408.ha-1002-1408.sh-3115-1408-1408.ca-1805-64.`) but the rest it messes up on, can anyone understand why? Am I doing something wrong, replacing a duplicated ID?

The figure code could be anything each user usually has a totally different one.

Comment: What do you mean "the rest it messes up on?" Please post what you expect it to do and what it actually does.

Comment: Seems to me that the way you store this data is wrong to begin with. If it isn't too late to change, I would use either json or xml to store the data, and deserialize it in the code to something that's easy to work with like a dictionary.

Comment: I think this cries out for a few classes. A player class with an Id, name, etc. and a "has a" relationship with clothes. Then a clothes class with head, hair, legs properties. Then you can set properties easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a regex solution would be suitable here:

```
Regex.Replace(
    FigureCode,
    "(hd-\\d+-)\\d+", 
    "${1}" + skinCode)
```

This is basically finding a substring that matches `(hd-\d+-)\d+` (hd followed by "-" followed by a number followed by "-" followed by another number), and replaces it with all of group 1 (`hd-\d+-`) plus your skin code.

Remember to `using System.Text.RegularExpressions`!

Comment: I must learn regex one day, it seems like a wonderful thing. I thank you kindly for this, it worked 100% :)